# Drawing triangle in OpenGL is insanely slow

Tags: c, opengl, geometry, vbo, glfw

I am making a simple program with GLFW3 and OpenGL. After almost 10 hours of researching, I was FINALLY able to draw a triangle (It took me so long because I did not want to use functions such as `glVertex3f()` and my dumb graphics card only supports OpenGL up to 2.1). So after doing a small celebration dance, I realized that not only was the triangle not taking up the whole screen when I resized, it takes more than a second to resize! Here's my code:

```
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static const GLfloat vertices[] = {
    -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,
     1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,
     0.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
};

static void drawScene() {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, NULL);
    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
}

static void error_callback(int error, const char* description) {
    fputs(description, stderr);
}

static void key_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mods) {
    if (key == GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE && action == GLFW_PRESS) {
        glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, GL_TRUE);
    }
}

int main(void) {
    GLFWwindow* window;
    glfwSetErrorCallback(error_callback);
    if (!glfwInit()) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Initiating GLFW failed.");
        return -1;
    }

    window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "Simple example", NULL, NULL);

    if (!window) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Creating a window failed.");
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }

    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    glfwSwapInterval(1);
    glfwSetKeyCallback(window, key_callback);

    GLuint triangleVBO;

    glGenBuffers(1, &triangleVBO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, triangleVBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, triangleVBO);

    glClearColor(0, 0, 0.2, 1);

    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
        drawScene();
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    glfwDestroyWindow(window);
    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

I am using a 32-bit Linux and OpenGL 2.1

Comment: Sounds like you don't have proper OpenGL drivers installed and are dropping into the software rasterizer fallback (although a triangle should appear quickly, even in software mode). What's the output of `glxinfo | grep renderer`?

Comment: @datenwolf doing `glxinfo | grep renderer` gives the output: `OpenGL renderer string: GeForce 7900 GT/GTO/PCIe/SSE2`

Comment: Hmm, not a software fallback then. What does `glxinfo | grep vendor` say?

Comment: @datenwolf `glxinfo | grep vendor` makes this outout: `server glx vendor string: NVIDIA Corporation
\nclient glx vendor string: NVIDIA Corporation
\nOpenGL vendor string: NVIDIA Corporation
`

Comment: @TheTromboneWilly: OK, that is glxinfo. But wehat does `glGetString(GL_RENDERER)` return from within your actual code? Also, you are not using the GL extension mechanism to load the GL 2.1 function pointers, neither do you include the correct function defintions. Your cod emight act really weird  in that case